# Slick2D AppGameContainer to AppletGameContainer

Tags: java, applet, program-entry-point, slick2d

Alright so I've made this game a while back and I've recently decided to put it onto my website! To make things short, I have no clue how to convert my game from an AppGameContainer to an AppletGameContainer. I've looked on the internet countless amounts of time and followed tutorials but can't seem to get it working!

Here's my code for my main class.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AppGameContainer game;

    try {
        game = new AppGameContainer(new Engine("Galactic Warrior"));
        game.setIcon("resources/images/ico3.png");
        game.setDisplayMode(640, 480, false); //640, 360 = 1080p ratio
        game.setMaximumLogicUpdateInterval(60);
        game.setTargetFrameRate(60);
        game.setAlwaysRender(true);
        game.setVSync(true);
        game.setShowFPS(false);
        game.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

So how exactly could I convert this into an AppletGameContainer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this too to begin with.

What you need to do is treat this like a normal application. DO NOT make another class for this. Please also take note the `main` method will NOT be called when the applet is loaded or loading.

Instead the applet is loaded by the `Init()`. You will need to do this:

```
private GameContainer container;

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    container = gc;

    gc.setShowFPS(false);
    gc.setTargetFrameRate(60);
    gc.setSmoothDeltas(true);
    gc.setAlwaysRender(true);
    gc.setVerbose(true);
}
```

Now the container will hold all the info about what kind of container it is. You can also do this to debug and amaze yourself too:

```
    if(container instanceof AppletGameContainer.Container){
        //This is an Applet
    }
```

If you are also adding custom paramaters into the HTML code you can do this:

```
((AppletGameContainer.Container) container).getParameter("HTMLParamKey");
```

with the HTML code:

```
<param name="HTMLParamKey" value="some value here">
```